# Slow performance of DataGridViewRow in .NET C# Application

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to figure out some behavior in an app that I'm supporting. The snippet is:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow pGridRow in grdEmail.Rows)
{
    pGridRow.Cells[0].Value = chkSelectAll.Checked;
    pCount = pGridRow.Index + 1;
}
```

Which is essentially trying to select all rows in a grid (check a box) when a select all checkbox is clicked.

When the grid has a few rows (hundred or so) it works beautifully. However, when I have around 5000 rows in it, this thing crawls. The `pGridRow.Cells[0].Value = chkSelectAll.Checked` command takes a second or so (timed by putting Console.prints above and below it).

Any idea would be appreciated in resolving this.

Comment: How many columns are in this DataGridView?
A second or two to find and set text of a cell seems a long long time..

Answer (score 3):

Try setting the properties:

```
grdEmail.AutoSizeRowsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeRowsMode.None;
grdEmail.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None;
```

Because it seems that for the other values of these two properties the DataGridView is trying to resize the rows and columns even if you are only checking some checkboxes in the grid.

Comment: I didn't think of this. I had a column with checkbox and it was taking too much time to check all. Setting `AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.None` solved the performance issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Showing thousands of rows at once is wasteful and makes it very difficult for users to find the data they need. I would definitely recommend pagination. Your users will thank you. (Unless they have specifically requested to see 5000 at once, which seems silly.)

Answer (score 0):

What is the point of having 5000 rows visible at once?

Can't this be paginated?
Can't the checkbox be sent as checked by default?

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to show 5000 rows at once. Sorting for one. 5000 isn't actually that much. I have users who would panic if they couldn't see all the data at once.

Answer (score 0):

Try modifying the underlying datasource (if any) directly instead of setting the value of the cell.

```
//assuming datasetFoo.Tables(0) is the DataSource of the DataGridView
foreach (DataRow rowFoo in datasetFoo.Tables(0) { 
        rowFoo ("Sel") = chkSelectAll.Checked; 
    }
```